# Space before \t is really inserted?

Tags: whitespace

Launch Emacs with `emacs -Q`, insert a line contains only a `\t` (`|` represents the cursor):

`\t|`

`M-x whitespace-mode`, it should looks like (`_` represents visual space):

`»________$`

Insert 2 spaces at the beginning of the line, it should now looks like:

`··»______$`

But what i want is:

`··»________$`

I'm a little confused why Emacs doesn't display the `\t` and 2 spaces before separately. Is the before 2 spaces really inserted? Can anyone help me?

**Edit:**

I encounter this problem when using `whitespace-mode` to show tab mark. The details can be found [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22357/whitespace-mode-tab-mark-disturb-my-indentation).

Comment: Isn't your edit *another* question?

Comment: Yes, I moved it here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22357/whitespace-mode-tab-mark-disturb-my-indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabs are not displayed as a fixed amount of spaces but as *whitespace stretching up to the next tab stop*. The [elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Usual-Display.html#Usual-Display) says:

> The tab character (character code 9) displays as whitespace
>        stretching up to the next tab stop column.  *Note (emacs)Text
>        Display::.  The variable ‘tab-width’ controls the number of spaces
>        per tab stop (see below).

<kbd>C-h v</kbd>`tab-width` says (emphasis mine):

> ...
>
> Documentation:
>   **Distance between tab stops** (for display of tab characters), in columns.
>   NOTE: This controls the display width of a TAB character, and not
>   the size of an indentation step.
>   This should be an integer greater than zero.

Comment: Therefore, spaces should come _after_ tabs.