# Whitespace-mode tab mark disturb my indentation

Tags: indentation, whitespace

I encounter this issue when i set `whitespace-style` to `(face tabs trailing tab-mark)` and turn on `whitespace-mode`.

When `whitespace-mode` is turned off, everything looks well:

[image: before-turn-on-whitespace-mode]

When `whitespace-mode` is turned on, it seems as if a tab mark `»` are actually inserted before tab char and the indentation looks strange:

[image: after-turn-on-whitespace-mode]

Is this a bug of `whitespace-mode`? How can i solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known problem as made evident in a comment in `whitespace.el`:

```
(defcustom whitespace-display-mappings
  '(
    (space-mark   ?\     [?\u00B7]     [?.])        ; space - centered dot
    (space-mark   ?\xA0  [?\u00A4]     [?_])        ; hard space - currency
    ;; NEWLINE is displayed using the face `whitespace-newline'
    (newline-mark ?\n    [?$ ?\n])          ; eol - dollar sign
    ;; (newline-mark ?\n    [?\u21B5 ?\n] [?$ ?\n]) ; eol - downwards arrow
    ;; (newline-mark ?\n    [?\u00B6 ?\n] [?$ ?\n]) ; eol - pilcrow
    ;; (newline-mark ?\n    [?\u00AF ?\n]  [?$ ?\n])    ; eol - overscore
    ;; (newline-mark ?\n    [?\u00AC ?\n]  [?$ ?\n])    ; eol - negation
    ;; (newline-mark ?\n    [?\u00B0 ?\n]  [?$ ?\n])    ; eol - degrees
    ;;
    ;; WARNING: the mapping below has a problem.
    ;; When a TAB occupies exactly one column, it will display the
    ;; character ?\xBB at that column followed by a TAB which goes to
    ;; the next TAB column.
    ;; If this is a problem for you, please, comment the line below.
    (tab-mark     ?\t    [?\u00BB ?\t] [?\\ ?\t])   ; tab - left quote mark
    )
  ...)
```

Considering that a display mapping introduces an extra preceding character, I don't see any way of solving this with whitespace-mode's current mode of operation.  Try using the described workaround instead.

Comment: Got it. BTW, Is there any other method to indicate a tab character visually except by `whitespace-mode` or   by tab background highlighting(such as `highlight-chars`)?

Comment: Well, you could always write your own package displaying things differently.  For instance a composition (think `prettify-symbols-mode`) or overlay (with a display property set to a string as wide as the tab) approach could be interesting.

Comment: Ok, I will try to write such a package although i don't know much about overlays. It seems to be very interesting. Thank you Wasamasa!

Answer (score 1):

The [whitespace4r.el](https://github.com/twlz0ne/whitespace4r.el) fixes this problem:

[image]