# Consistent tab alignment

Tags: tabs

As an evil I choose to use tabs.
I'm having trouble getting them to work like they do in other editors.

I want displayed tabs *aligned* to 2 columns (with no exceptions).

I have tab-width set to 2, but when tabs begin on an odd column they become 3 columns wide. Standard editors align to the next tab stop so in this case they become only 1 column wide (which is what I want).

Examples (where 'T+' is a tab with 2 chars, and 'x' is an ordinary character):

```
xxT+xx // same alignment on emacs and standard editors.
xT++xx // emacs.
xTxx   // standard editors. (This is what I'm after)
```

How do I achieve this (preferably globally, but primarily for C/C++/bash/text).

Note: This question is entirely about the *display* of existing tabs.

Comment: There is a ton of confusion about what is "tab" in Emacs, so please be specific when you say "I have tab width set at 2".

Comment: The variable named "tab-width" is set to 2, (I also played around with some other variables without success). However, I don't know if that's the variable I should be using, I'm just looking for any way to achieve the said alignment.

Comment: How do you know `tab-width` is set to 2?  Where is it set to 2?  It's a buffer-local variable, so setting it in your .emacs won't make a difference in your C-mode buffers.  IOW *be specific*.

Comment: I'm new to emacs (Kate's developed hideous bugs so I'm shopping for an alternative) so sorry if I'm not understanding how it all works yet. Options->Customize Emacs->Browse Customization Groups->Emacs->Editing->Editing Basics->Tab Width = 2. But my current setup isn't important - I just want to know how I *should* be achieving this.

Comment: If you set tab-width to a value other than the default you're likely to run into problems whenever you try to read code written by someone using a standard tab width.

Comment: Qudit: That doesn't worry me. Most code I read doesn't use a standard tab width - tabs are used for indentation so all widths are appropriate. However, almost all standard editors (well, the ones I've used: kate, gedit, notepad, xed, and a handful of others) use the method I've described above to align tabs, so I'm just trying to emulate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce what you see.  I've done the following:

```
emacs -Q
Options
-> Customize Emacs
-> Browse Customization Groups
-> Emacs -> Editing
-> Editing Basics
-> Tab Width
Replace the 8 with a 2
Click on `State` -> Set for Current Session
```

then I went back to `*scratch*` and typed

```
x C-q TAB xx
```

at which point I saw

```
xTxx
```

rather than the

```
xT++xx
```

[ where `T` and `+` both stand for whitespace.  ]

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was using whitespace.el and I didn't realize this had any effect on layout (and I didn't know about -Q, that's handy, thanks). It seems whitespace.el is the source of the problem, now I just need to figure out why.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Seems I've hit this bug: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22357/whitespace-mode-tab-mark-disturb-my-indentation